# How lodash "_.every" works with an empty predication param?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to replace lodash `_.every` method with the native `every` from Array.prototype.

I faced with the case when array is checked with the empty predication like this `_.every(arr)`.

What should I place into a native `every` method to get the same result as in the lodash?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your main question is how to make `Array.prototype.every` and `_.every` behave the same way when predicate is empty. Indeed `_.every([1,2,3])` returns `true` while `([1,2,3]).every()` throws 'undefined is not a function'. What about returning `true` if case there is no predicate? No need to call `Array.prototype.every` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, the [`_.every()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#every) function takes the [`_.identity()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#identity) as the default predicate.

So we can substitute the function v => v for this (the identity function simply returns the first argument).

```js
const testInputs = [[true, false], [true, true], [false, false], [false, true]]

for(let i = 0; i < testInputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Test #${i+1}`);
    console.log('_.every():', _.every(testInputs[i]));
    console.log('Array.every():', testInputs[i].every(v => v));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```